# Extract all frames timestamps with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

**Q1.** Which `ffmpeg` command should I use to extract each frame number associated with its timestamp (time in ms from the starting of the video) ?

Expected result :

```
frame, ts
1, 34
2, 67
3, 101
4, 123
...
```

**Q2.** Are those timestamps safe to use as a key to point to a frame ?

In other terms, if I use other tools than `ffmpeg` to do the same thing, will I get exactly the same timestamps.

---

Material: http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4

Answer (score 9):

**A1**. You can get close by running

`ffprobe video.mp4 -select_streams v -show_entries frame=coded_picture_number,pkt_pts_time -of csv=p=0:nk=1 -v 0`

Output is

```
0.000000,0
0.040000,3
0.080000,2
0.120000,4
0.160000,1
0.200000,7
0.240000,6
0.280000,8
0.320000,5
```

where presented frame `n` is on line `n` (starting from 1).

The first column is the timestamp in seconds; the 2nd column is the encoding and decoding and file storage order of the frames.

**A2**. Should be. Other s/w may remove starting offset - ffprobe doesn't. Other s/w may adjust timings taking into account audio delay or edit lists..etc.